# file download via http post is returning the zip file contents

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I could see many related topics, but I have a specific problem. I am using spring boot controller to download a zip file. I am able to download the file when it is http verb get, but as I have to pass a big json payload I changed to post. Since then instead of downloading it as file it is responding the contents of the file with some ascii characters. Below is the method in controller for downloading the file.

```
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "file could not be found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "File was created sucessfully") })
@PostMapping(path="/download-file/1.0", produces="application/zip")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile(
        @ApiParam(value = "File creation contents", required = true) @RequestBody InputDetailsVO inputDetailsVO) {
    File file = null;
    InputStreamResource resource = null;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    try {
        //Creating InputStreamResource out of zip file
        resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));          
        String contentType = "application/zip";
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(contentType)) {
           headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType));
        }
        headers.add("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Issue with file creation",e);

    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .contentType(MediaType
                          .parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE))
             .headers(headers).body(resource);
}
```

Below is the response I am getting instead of file download

```
    PK;��N <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employeeDetails>
<name>Harry</name>
<age>30</30>
<email>test@test.com</test>
</employeeDetails>PK�qB�@Y;YPK;��N�qB�@Y;Yemployee details.xmlPKL�Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, you can download any type of file. I assume that InputDetailsVO contains the name of the file or you can have your own logic to pick the file name. On the top of this method, you can provide swagger related annotations.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/download-file/1.0", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> downloadFile(@RequestBody InputDetailsVO inputDetailsVO) {
    String dirPath = "your-location-path";
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    try {
       String fileName = inputDetailsVO.getFileName();
      fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(dirPath + fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
        .body(fileBytes);
  }
```

Comment: I still see the same response.

Comment: Can you post the InputDetailsVO class, I will generate json and check.

Comment: It is the contents of the file to zipped {
 "name": "Harry",
 "age": "30",
 "email": "test@test.com",
 "active": "y"
}

Comment: I just transform this data into an XML format and based on number of employees, i generate one xml file for each employee and zip the contents

Comment: For a quick testing, just hard code the zip file name and see whether you are able to download or not.

Comment: I am able to download if it is get and for post it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar use case. I am sharing the code which had solved the issue.

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/download",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/zip" )
        public ResponseEntity<?> download(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
        {
            //Some Code...

            File file = new File("F:\\Folder\\Folder\\Folder\\"+filename); 
            InputStreamResource resource2 = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
            response.setContentType("application/zip");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\""));
            response.setHeader("responseType", "arraybuffer");
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", ""+file.length());

            return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(resource2,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        }
```

Comment: Get will work, I am checking out for post. I need to take json as input