# Spring: can't download a file from a server (FileInputStream)

Tags: java, spring, download

I can't download a file from the controller. No exceptions are thrown.

User clicks a button in the view and the method is called correctly and it reaches it's end but a file never gets downloaded.

Edit: File is found all right. Also, the button user clicks is in a modal.

```
public void downloadFile(Long fileId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws HibernateValidationException, IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    Attachment attachment = attachmentDao.getById(fileId);
    String fileName = attachment.getName();
    File file = new File(FILE_DIRECTORY, attachment.getSysname());
    String contentType = request.getSession().getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getAbsolutePath());
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"UTF-8")+"\"");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
    is.close();
}
```

Comment: Check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479684/file-download-via-http-post-is-returning-the-zip-file-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't something with my back-end method. It was front-end.

Method was like this, and downloading files in this form is impossible as I found out:

```
    this.downloadFile = function(file) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/app/downloadFile',
            params: {
                id: file.id,
            }
        })
    }
```

I had to change it to:

```
    this.downloadFile = function(file) {
        $window.location.href = '/app/downloadFile?id=' + file.id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is void. So, correct file downloading:

```
try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(generatedFile)) {
                ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(is.readAllBytes());
                return ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + UriEncoder.encode(realReportName))
                        .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
                        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
                        .body(resource);
            } finally {
                Files.deleteIfExists(generatedFile.toPath());
            }
```

And controller declaration :

```
public ResponseEntity getFile()
```

Comment: application/vnd.ms-excel - this is Excel of course. Its easy to google for other formats

Comment: It didn't work either. So I looked into front-end. I posted an answer. Thanks anyways.